# How do you hide an element in HTML securely?

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption, password-protection

How could I hide an HTML element securely to where users cannot simply right-click the page, view the source code, and change the "display" property from "none" to "block"? I need a way to be able to hide a YouTube video until someone enters the webpage password, and then the video is revealed. I don't want anyone who doesn't have the password to be able to see the video. I have already encrypted my JavaScript code, but I have not found a way to prevent people from revealing the elements beforehand.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The only thing you can do is reload the page with new content from the server that doesn't include the item(s) you don't want people to see.

Comment: It's not possible to encrypt your JavaScript code. You can obfuscate or minify it though.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with only client side controls. A user can simply turn off JavaScript in their browser and change the display property of the video. The best solution would be to do what Scott Marcus said and simply not have the video in the page that you are allowing the user to have access to until they have entered a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, with the help of PHP.
Step 1 - Change the page from HTML to PHP.
Step 2 - in the index page (I am assuming that, the video you are referring to, is there on the index page)
Step 3 - Keep the Password Form, then the video. Remember to encapsulate both the Password Form, and the video in  scripts.

Logic for the form - Form will accept the data, send it to a php script for verification of password, and then send a POST variable back to the index page, if authentication successfull.

Now what you need to do, is that, set an if condition on the form that, if POST variable is unset, then only it will be processed.
And the vice-versa for the video, that if POST variable is set, i.e., auth was successful, then Video will load.

Added Advantage - Since using PHP with if statements, so, no-one can even find out the video link, if the donot have the password, because if the if condition stands false, PHP wont even be printing those statements as HTML statements for the Browser Engine to process.